# Is a (axial) rotation an absolute or relative motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

When a wheel is spinning is this for all observers so, or could there be observers who could think that they are spinning?

Comment: Please explain your question.

Comment: If an observer rotates with the wheel, then, to him, the wheel would be stationary, and the room would be spinning. Try driving down a long straight road, and imagining that you and your car is stationary and that the road and the surrounding scenery are moving.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask the wheel, everything around it will be spinning. So yes, there are observers who could think that they are spinning.

The frame of the wheel is not rest frame because it is rotating. Rotation is an accelerated motion and therefore you cannot define a rest frame there. For that you need the machinery of general relativity, but then it would not be Newtonian mechanics any more.

With “axial rotation” you probably mean a mechanical rotation about an axis? The term is also used in quantum field theory where it means something completely different.

Comment: One can deal with rotating reference frames in classical mechanics without the machinery of general relativity; this just requires making a coordinate transformation, one which introduces fictional forces. (Even accelerating frames in special relativity can be adequately dealt with without appeal to general relativity, as for example in the twins paradox, which can be resolved without reference to general relativity.)

Comment: Yes, I forgot. Simple rotating frame just has some cross products in it, then you get centripetal and Coriolis force.